# Code not working in Xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I just upgraded to Xcode 8 and Swift 3 yesterday. I have some code that has worked in Xcode 7, but now I get a warning in Xcode 8. I converted all my code to Swift 3, but this code still gives me a warning. Here's my code:

```
let priority = DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority.default
    DispatchQueue.global(priority: priority).async {

}
```

Here's a picture of the code and the warning I'm getting:

[image: My problem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift 3 it's pretty easy

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {

}
```

It's the short form of

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {

}
```

and `.default` is the default priority.

Comment: Thanks that fixed my second line of code, but I still get a warning on the first line. How can I fix that?

Comment: Delete the first line, `global()` includes default priority

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it!

Answer (score -1):

I think `[this][1]` is what you are looking for? The API has changed in 10.11...

```
DispatchQueue.global(priority: priority).async {
```

is now...

```
DispatchQueue.global(attributes: .qosDefault).async { // various attributes you can use
```

which is a generalization of the original. Or even shorter...

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
```